# How to merge 2 branches using git?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have created branch A from master branch. After some commits, I then created branch B on top of branch A. After some commits on branch B, I now want to merge branch B to branch A and then delete branch B. What is the right way to do so? Or should I just delete A and merge B back to master?

Comment: Use git merge? What's the specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is all you need `git merge A B`?

Answer (score 0):

So you didn't do any changes on `A` after you branched `B`?
Then you can simply do `git checkout master && git merge B`.

If you want to merge `B` into `A` do the same: `git checkout A && git merge B`.

If `A` and `B` are non-pushed local branches, you may also consider rebasing first to get a linear history as a result if you made commits on master or there were commits made on master in remote since you branched off `A` and `B`.